# npm ERR! Missing script: "seed"

Tags: error-handling, graphql, npm-scripts, npm-start

I have a feeling it has to do with me putting something in the wrong file or I am forgetting to add something. When I run  --- "npm run seed" the error I receive is:

" npm ERR! Missing script: "seed"

I am trying to get into my GraphQL playground, and I have already installed Homebrew and did an npm install. I ran Mongod, and I have everything. please help, lol.